# What's the rationale for the block argument?

Tags: ruby

I'm just learning about Ruby, and am having trouble seeing the point of the so-called "block argument" (which can be appended to method invocations).

AFAICT, the "block argument" works like any run-of-the-mill callback argument in other programming languages (or in Ruby itself, for that matter), but are more limited in that one can attach at most one "block argument" to a method invocation, while there's no upper limit on the number of callback arguments a method/function can be designed to accept.

(In case clarification is needed, by "callback" all I mean is a function *F* that another function *G* receives (as one of its arguments) and in turn calls.)

I figure that there must be *something* that one can do with a block argument that can't be done *just as easily* with a callback (otherwise, it's hard to justify supporting a special syntax for block arguments), but I can't figure out what this "something" could be.

My question is just that:

What can be done with a "block argument" that couldn't be done with regular callback?

---

EDIT: An earlier comment (now deleted) said that block arguments are better described as "closures" than as "callbacks".  In my book, closures are a special case of callbacks.  One can, if one wants, replace "callback" with "closure" in my post.  The post's question still remains (unless, of course, "block arguments" were the only way to create closures in Ruby, but if this were the case, it in itself would raise more questions than it answers).

Comment: OK, yehuda gives an elaborate example of where they differ http://yehudakatz.com/2012/01/10/javascript-needs-blocks/ but really I don't think this matters in most cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I figure that there must be something that one can do with a block argument that can't be done just as easily with a callback (otherwise,

Yes. Blocks are a sort of "syntactic sugar", but they are also functionally quite different from "callback function" in a language like JavaScript.

For one thing, the `return` keyword functions very differently than it does in functions and methods both in Ruby and other languages.

Inside a block, `return` jumps out of the *containing method*, while in a method `return` jumps out of (obviously) the method.

This is important for the following case:

```
def find_by_email(users, search_email)
  users.each do |user|
    # return all the way out of find_by_email
    return user if user.email == search_email
  end

  nil
end
```

Here, we're using `each` to iterate over a collection. If some condition is me inside the block, the user is returned **all the way out of the containing method**.

This doesn't work with a function. Compare the "identical" JavaScript code, which doesn't work as intended:

```
function findUserByEmail(users, searchEmail) {
  users.forEach(function (user) {
    if (user.email == searchEmail) {
      // return out of `forEach`
      return user;
    }
  });
  // broken
}
```

Comment: OK, I think I get: the block argument is almost like bit of code that one "injects" (or "grafts") directly into a method...  It's still puzzling that such arguments are limited to at most one.  If more than one were allowed, it would amount to a built-in syntax to support the strategy/policy pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anything can be done with blocks that can't be done with passing functions (such as in javascript) . 
I think that the creators of ruby figured that in 95% of cases, you want to pass only one callback to a function, not more. So they created very nice syntax for that:

```
 Post.all.map { |post| puts post.title }
```

Compare to javascript

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
   DO SOMETHING
 }
```

To sum: I think that passing blocks is a syntax sugar in ruby, comparable to passing functions in js but nicer looking. In the majority of cases you will want to pass one block (or callback) anyway.

Comment: For the record, modern JS has greatly streamlined the [syntax for anonymous functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), *without* thereby limiting how many of these functions can be passed as arguments to other functions.